# How can an iOS7-style "Now Playing" button be added to an UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar

I'd like to add an iOS7 Music app style "Now Playing" button to the UINavigationBar

The button should have:

- two lines of text
- a right pointing chevron

How can this be achieved?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need the image for the chevron. If that's okay for you then you can create a UIButton with proper title and image insets and pass to `initWithCustomView:` method.
Note: you will also need to set `numberOfLines = 2` for this button which as far as I know you can not do in IB